# Jquery carousel with 360 loop

Tags: jquery, slider

I have designed carousel.
I want two slides rotate in 360 degree with looping. According to my development team the JavaScript they are using will not support my design and requirement. Can some one help me out on what i have to do next. Should I change the design? If yes what script I need to use  support continuous sliding with 360 loop.

Please advise. ![`Slider that i have design`][1]

Here is the JS code

```
    (function (a) {
    a.tiny = a.tiny || {};
    a.tiny.carousel = {
        options: {
            start: 1,
            display: 1,
            axis: "x",
            controls: true,
            pager: false,
            interval: false,
            intervaltime: 3000,
            rewind: false,
            animation: true,
            duration: 1000,
            callback: null
        }
    };
    a.fn.tinycarousel_start = function () {
        a(this).data("tcl").start()
    };
    a.fn.tinycarousel_stop = function () {
        a(this).data("tcl").stop()
    };
    a.fn.tinycarousel_move = function (c) {
        a(this).data("tcl").move(c - 1, true)
    };

    function b(q, e) {
        var i = this,
            h = a(".viewport:first", q),
            g = a(".overview:first", q),
            k = g.children(),
            f = a(".next:first", q),
            d = a(".prev:first", q),
            l = a(".pager:first", q),
            w = 0,
            u = 0,
            p = 0,
            j = undefined,
            o = false,
            n = true,
            s = e.axis === "x";

        function m() {
            if (e.controls) {
                d.toggleClass("disable", p <= 0);
                f.toggleClass("disable", !(p + 1 < u))
            }
            if (e.pager) {
                var x = a(".pagenum", l);
                x.removeClass("active");
                a(x[p]).addClass("active")
            }
        }

        function v(x) {
            if (a(this).hasClass("pagenum")) {
                i.move(parseInt(this.rel, 10), true)
            }
            return false
        }

        function t() {
            if (e.interval && !o) {
                clearTimeout(j);
                j = setTimeout(function () {
                    p = p + 1 === u ? -1 : p;
                    n = p + 1 === u ? false : p === 0 ? true : n;
                    i.move(n ? 1 : -1)
                }, e.intervaltime)
            }
        }

        function r() {
            if (e.controls && d.length > 0 && f.length > 0) {
                d.click(function () {
                    i.move(-1);
                    return false
                });
                f.click(function () {
                    i.move(1);
                    return false
                })
            }
            if (e.interval) {
                q.hover(i.stop, i.start)
            }
            if (e.pager && l.length > 0) {
                a("a", l).click(v)
            }
        }
        this.stop = function () {
            clearTimeout(j);
            o = true
        };
        this.start = function () {
            o = false;
            t()
        };
        this.move = function (y, z) {
            p = z ? y : p += y;
            if (p > -1 && p < u) {
                var x = {};
                x[s ? "left" : "top"] = -(p * (w * e.display));
                g.animate(x, {
                    queue: false,
                    duration: e.animation ? e.duration : 0,
                    complete: function () {
                        if (typeof e.callback === "function") {
                            e.callback.call(this, k[p], p)
                        }
                    }
                });
                m();
                t()
            }
        };

        function c() {
            w = s ? a(k[0]).outerWidth(true) : a(k[0]).outerHeight(true);
            var x = Math.ceil(((s ? h.outerWidth() : h.outerHeight()) / (w * e.display)) - 1);
            u = Math.max(1, Math.ceil(k.length / e.display) - x);
            p = Math.min(u, Math.max(1, e.start)) - 2;
            g.css(s ? "width" : "height", (w * k.length));
            i.move(1);
            r();
            return i
        }
        return c()
    }
    a.fn.tinycarousel = function (d) {
        var c = a.extend({}, a.tiny.carousel.options, d);
        this.each(function () {
            a(this).data("tcl", new b(a(this), c))
        });
        return this
    }
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 0):

Upload it to http://jsfiddle.net and give some more info on what you are trying to do. 
a rotating 3D model?

http://www.360slider.com/

https://github.com/heartcode/360-Image-Slider

If I right understood.